# Add tag to load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-java-sdk

I am adding tags to load balancer in java using below code:

```
AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient elbClient = new AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient(credentials);
AddTagsRequest addTagReq = new AddTagsRequest();
addTagReq.setTags("Name","Value");
```

However , it is giving compile error in setTags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though each tag consists of a key and an optional value, you cannot directly add tags like a map, you first need to declare a collection of `Tags`:

```
AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient elbClient = new AmazonElasticLoadBalancingClient(credentials);

ArrayList<Tag> requestTags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
requestTags.add(new Tag("keyname1","value1"));

AddTagsRequest addTagReq = new AddTagsRequest();
addTagReq.setTags(requestTags);

elbClient.addTags(addTagReq);
```